# By deliberately doing the opposite of what is wanted or expected

Tags: adverbs

> Some people behave badly by **deliberately** doing the opposite of what is wanted or expected.

Is deliberately an evaluative or focusing adverb?

Comment: "Bad behaves is who behaves..." doesn't make a lot of sense, so your example is difficult to evaluate.

Comment: "by deliberately doing the opposite of what is wanted or expected." I want to know adverb position after preposition "By" before gerund "Doing" that I like to know

Answer (score 0):

**Deliberately** is a focusing adverb *in your example*. When spoken, it is emphasised so as to focus the listener's attention - the speaker wants to talk only about one sort of behaviour. Deliberately modifies only "doing".

Evaluative adverbs are used by the speaker to comment or give an opinion on something. Evaluative adverbs modify the entire clause.

Deliberately, he said "Keep your hands away from your pockets."

The function of an adverb - and thus its category - will change with context.